# Context free grammar: Meaning of notation ww^R

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, palindrome

A common example in CFG is the palindrome example. These examples often contain the $\ ww^R$ notation for the string.

An example from my class could be:

Strings $\ ww^R$ over the alphabet $\ \Sigma = \{0,1 \} $ (a subset of
palindromes over $\ \Sigma $), or

$$\ L=\{ww^R ｜ w = (a + b)^+ \}$$

My confusion lies in the notation $\ w^R $, i don't understand what the purpose of this is.

Comment: I think it means whatever be your 'w' just write it in reverse in $w^R$

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w^R$ is simply the string $w$ reversed. For example, if $w = abb$, then $w^R = bba$. It is easy to see then that the strings of the form $ww^R$ are exactly the palindromes, such as $abbbba$.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you. My material for this class often use a new symbol or letter without any explanation. I should maybe have been able to figure this one out when I knew it's about palindromes though :)